# Accessing session and flash when unit-testing a custom plug

Tags: unit-testing, session, phoenix-framework, flash-message

I have a login requirement plug that pretty much resembles the one described in [this example by Thoughtbot](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/testing-elixir-plugs). I want to add a flash notification when the user is redirected. It works in the browser, but not when testing it in isolation.

The plug:

```elixir
# In webs/plugs/require_login.ex
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.RequireLogin do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(opts), do: opts
    if false # real user authentication omitted
      conn
    else
      conn
      |> Phoenix.Controller.put_flash(:error, "Login required.")
      |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect(to: "/")
      |> halt
    end
  end
end
```

The test used for this:

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.RequireLoginTest do
  use MyApp.ConnCase

  test "user is redirected when authentication fails" do
    conn = conn |> MyApp.Plugs.RequireLogin.call(%{})

    assert Phoenix.Controller.get_flash(conn, :error) == "Login required."
    assert redirected_to(conn) == "/"
  end
end
```

The error message I get is:

> (ArgumentError) flash not fetched, call fetch_flash/2

The error occurs in the plug module but if I comment out the `put_session` line there, the error moves to my test file.

I understand the session store is configured in `lib/my_app/endpoint.ex` but how can I re-use this configuration so that I can unit-test plugs?

Here's how the plug is hooked into the router:

```elixir
# web/router.ex
pipeline :browser do
  # the Phoenix default
end

scope "/", MyApp do
  pipe_through [:browser, MyApp.Plugs.RequireLogin]
  resource "/protected", MyController, only: [:index]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using [bypass_through](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#bypass_through/1). I did not "fire" a request using e.g. `Phoenix.ConnTest.get/3`, resulting in the plug pipeline not being called. As soon as I added `get/3`, the flash hash became available.

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.RequireLoginTest do
  use MyApp.ConnCase

  test "user is redirected when authentication fails", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = conn
           |> with_pipeline
           |> MyApp.Plugs.RequireLogin.call(%{})

    assert Phoenix.Controller.get_flash(conn, :error) == "Login required."
    assert redirected_to(conn) == "/"
  end

  defp with_pipeline(conn) do
    conn
    |> bypass_through(MyApp.Router, [:browser])
    |> get("/protected-uri") # any uri, bypass_through ignores the router rules
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
First thing that comes to my mind is you are missing param in your test.

Your conn is generated probably somewhere in your ConnCase:

```
setup tags do
  ...

  {:ok, conn: Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn()}
end
```

And your test should looks like this:

```
test "user is redirected when authentication fails", %{conn: conn} do
```

to be able to use this conn.

Second thing is that there is no request(get/post etc.) in your test and your conn probably does not pass through `:browser` pipeline.

Comment: Thank you @amatalai. My plug is doing alright in a browser-session, just not when run from a unit test. I've updated my question to clarify that.

Comment: your answer made me dig up how to force the use of a pipeline in a test. I found `bypass_through/3` – see my answer below. Thanks!